# JWT and Unit Tesing with Dependency injection

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I'm new in the world of OOP PHP, so if I did something wrong feel free to correct me.

In order to use JWT(JSON Web Token) functions, I need to instantiation it in my constructor, while with test_registration_input_validation I try to write unit tests for the methods in RegisterController, but I can't reach them because I can't instantiation the RegisterController. The constructor has an input parameter and JWTAuth has it's own input parameters, so it's an endless circle. Any thoughts?

```
class RegisterController extends Controller{

public $jwtauth;


public function __construct(JWTAuth $jwtauth){ 

    $this->jwtauth = $jwtauth;

}


 public function test_registration_input_validation(){

    $register = new RegisterController(new JWTAuth());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're writing a unit test for your controller, you should be mocking your dependencies, rather than passing an instance of them, so that you can isolate that component. [Mockery](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/) comes with Laravel out of the box and is well-suited to this use case.

I note that you're already using dependency injection to insert JWTAuth, which will make this easier. You can create a mock of JWTAuth as follows:

```
$jwt = Mockery::mock('Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth');
```

Then pass it to the controller:

```
$register = new RegisterController($jwt);
```

Then, you can set up whatever expectations you need on the mock and hardcode the response it should return. For example:

```
$jwt->shouldReceive('getToken')->once()->andReturn('foo');
```

Then you should be able to call the controller, and as long as you have mocked out all the calls to JWTAuth, it should work:

```
$response = $register->index();
```

You'll probably need to refer to the documentation for Mockery to mock out all your expectations, but this should solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry i din't have time to test it. I'll do it now!

Comment: It works, thank you Matthew for your help! I will take a deeper look on Mockery

Comment: Glad to hear it. If the answer solved the issue, please accept it.